# Python loop in beautiful soup regex list

Tags: regex, python-3.x, loops, beautifulsoup

When i run the code below, i get three lists, one below the other vertically. 
I want them to be horizontal, separated by a comma (similar to the last print list statement, where the data is separated by a comma). 
I tried rearranging the for loop statements, and I get all sorts of combinations, but nothing like I wanted that I described above. Please help!

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import re

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www5.statcan.gc.ca/cimt-cicm/topNCountryCommodities-marchandises?lang=eng&chapterId=27&sectionId=0&refMonth=2&refYr=2017&freq=6&countryId=999&usaState=0&provId=1&arrayId=9900000&commodityId=271111&commodityName=Natural+gas%2C+liquefied&topNDefault=10&tradeType=3').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')

regexQ = re.compile('.*Date1 Qty.*')
regexC = re.compile('.*Footnote.*')
regexV = re.compile('.*Date1 Val.*')

for countryPart in soup.findAll("a",{"href":regexC}):
        Country = countryPart.text.strip()
        print(Country)
for DatePart in soup.findAll("td",{"headers":regexQ}):
        Quantity = DatePart.text.strip()
        print(Quantity)
for ValPart in soup.findAll("td",{"headers": regexV}):
        Value = ValPart.text.strip()
        print(Value)

list = [Country,Quantity,Value]
print(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Also, you don't need `.*` to match any character while using regex in BeautifulSoup.

Use this to get what you want:

```
regexQ = re.compile('Date1 Qty')
regexC = re.compile('Footnote')
regexV = re.compile('Date1 Val')

country = [x.text.strip() for x in soup.find_all("a", {"href": regexC})]
quantity = [x.text.strip() for x in soup.find_all("td", {"headers": regexQ})]
value = [x.text.strip() for x in soup.find_all("td", {"headers": regexV})]

total_list = [list(x) for x in zip(country, quantity, value)]
for item in total_list:
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
['World', '282,911,404', '67,284,637']
['Equatorial Guinea', '146,027,530', '40,493,766']
['Trinidad and Tobago', '136,883,464', '26,790,695']
['Japan', '410', '176']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without using `regex`. Try the below approach instead to achieve the same. I used `list comprehensions`.

Using `urllib`:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = urlopen("http://www5.statcan.gc.ca/cimt-cicm/topNCountryCommodities-marchandises?lang=eng&chapterId=27&sectionId=0&refMonth=2&refYr=2017&freq=6&countryId=999&usaState=0&provId=1&arrayId=9900000&commodityId=271111&commodityName=Natural+gas%2C+liquefied&topNDefault=10&tradeType=3")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.read(),"lxml")
for items in soup.find_all(class_="ResultRow"):
    data = [item.get_text(" ",strip=True) for item in items.find_all(["th","td"])[1:4]]
    print(data)
```

Using `requests`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("http://www5.statcan.gc.ca/cimt-cicm/topNCountryCommodities-marchandises?lang=eng&chapterId=27&sectionId=0&refMonth=2&refYr=2017&freq=6&countryId=999&usaState=0&provId=1&arrayId=9900000&commodityId=271111&commodityName=Natural+gas%2C+liquefied&topNDefault=10&tradeType=3")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for items in soup.find_all(class_="ResultRow"):
    data = [item.get_text(" ",strip=True) for item in items.find_all(["th","td"])[1:4]]
    print(data)
```

Output:

```
['World', '282,911,404', '67,284,637']
['Equatorial Guinea', '146,027,530', '40,493,766']
['Trinidad and Tobago', '136,883,464', '26,790,695']
['Japan', '410', '176']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try collapsing your Country and other results to a list.

Then try this:

```
for mylist in lists:
    print(*mylist, end=", ")
```